# Rails radio yes/no buttons to show more fields

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `item.rb model` with yes or no `radio buttons`:

```
enum stock: { "No": "1", "Yes": "2" }
```

and in the view:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :stock, Item.stock, :first, :first %>
```

and if I click on yes I want more fields to show up, which I have inside this:

```
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
</div
```

I'm trying to use this javascript in order to achieve that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function yesnoCheck() {
          if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
              document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
          }
          else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

      }

  </script>
```

with this but nothing is happening:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :stock, Item.stock, :first, :first, onclick:"javascript:yesnoCheck();", :id=>"yesCheck" %>
```

Any idea on how I can make this work?

**Update 1**

Now I'm doing this and the when I click either yes or no the content inside `<div id="ifYes" style="display:none;"></div>` is showing.

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :stock, Item.stock, :first, :first, onChange:"getValue(this)" %>



 <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(getValue){
          $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
              $('#ifYes').show();
          });
      });

  </script>
```

But how can hide the fields if I click on no?

Comment: Maybe you should try `onChange`

Comment: Thanks for the reply@Jack Ashton !  I'm kind of a newbie... how exactly can I implement the `onCharge` function with what I'm trying to achieve with the above code?

Comment: Just as simple as `onclick` I think, just change the `onclick:"javascript:yesnoCheck();"` to `onchange:"javascript:yesnoCheck();"`

Comment: And what about the javascript, which one should I use?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use your function `yesnoCheck()`, it seems ok

Comment: I'm doing this `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :stock, Item.stock, :first, :first, onchange:"javascript:yesnoCheck();", :id=>"yesCheck" %>` and if I  inspect the element  for the radio buttons to check if the id is  `yesCheck`, I get this `item_stock_yes` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('your-element').click(function(){
    $('ifYes').show();
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jedi... can you please check my questions, I have an update on there now!

Comment: Same but just say `$('your-element').hide();`

Comment: Thanks @jedi!!  I added two different id's to the radio buttons and create one script to hide and the other to show

Answer (score 2):

You have two radio buttons that may be checked or not. You just have to select the one that is checked:

```
$(document).change('input[type=radio][name="foo[stock]"]', function(){
  var selection = document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name="foo[stock]"]:checked');
  $('#ifYes').toggle(selection.value === 'Yes');
});
```

If you put the selector as argument to `$(document).change()` you don't need to put it in a ready function.

I would anyways advise against putting this type of code, but rather encapsulate into some managed framework. For instance with stimulus.js, you can do the following (once for all, in the main application JS):

```
window.Application = Stimulus.Application.start()

class ShowerController extends Stimulus.Controller {
  static get targets() { return ['detail'] }

  toggle(event) {
    switch (event.target.value) {
      case 'Yes':
        this.detailTarget.style.display = '';
        break;
      case 'No':
        this.detailTarget.style.display = 'none';
        break;
      default:
        console.warn("Unexpected value", event.target.value)
    }
  }
}

window.Application.register('shower', ShowerController);
```

Then, whenever you need a show/hide behavior:

```
<div data-controller="shower">
  <label>Yes <input type="radio" name="foo" value="Yes" data-action="shower#toggle"></label>
  <label>No <input type="radio" name="foo" value="No" data-action="shower#toggle"></label>
  <div data-target="shower.detail" style="{display: none}">
    Anything
  </div>
</div>
```

This way you can use the "show/hide" behavior with many other cases, just adding the proper data-controller, data-action and data-target attributes, everything will work.